# goodness of fit in pymc and plotting discrepancies

Tags: python-2.7, pymc, goodness-of-fit

I'm using PYMC 2.3.4. I found terrific. Now I would like to do some goodness of the fit and plot discrpancies how shown in section 7.3 of the documentation (https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelchecking.html)
In the documentation they say that you need 3 inputs for the discrepancy plot

1. x: the data
2. x_sim: the posterior distribution sample
3. x_exp:expected value
   I can understand the first two but not the third

This the code

```
Sero=[0,1,4,2,2,7,13,17,90]

Pop=[ 15,145,170,132,107,57,68,57,251]

for i in range(len(Pop)):
   prob[i] = pymc.Uniform(`prob_%i' % i, 0,1.0)

serobservation=pymc.Binomial('serobservation',n=Pop,p=prob,value=Sero,observed=True)
pobservation=pymc.Binomial('pobservation',n=Pop,p=prob)
mod=pymc.Model([serobservation,pobservation,prob])
mc=pymc.MCMC(mod)
mc.sample(20000)
```

Everything works fine and then I try to plot discrepancy but I don't **Know what to put as expected values** Can you help on that?
till now I've done in this way:

```
D = pymc.discrepancy( Sero,pobservation,serobservation)
pymc.Matplot.discrepancy_plot(D, name='D', report_p=True)
```

but I have the error

```
AttributeError: 'Binomial' object has no attribute 'trace'
```

What can I do? Can you please provide me of an example for dummy of how create the expected values?
Moreover when I use the function

```
pymc.Matplot.gof_plot(pobservation,Sero )
```

only a plot for the last entries of the array is done
How can I have a plot for each entry?

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the built-in stochastics, there are `expval` functions that is the expected value for that distribution (in the case of binomial, the function is just `binomial_expval`, which is just `p*n`).

In general, I recommend using the `gof_plot` to produce posterior predictive plots, rather than `discrepancy_plot`. There are some issues with your code:

1. Its not clear why you are building a list of `prob` nodes, rather than just specifying a vector-valued `Uniform`:

   ```
   prob = pymc.Uniform('prob', 0, 1, size=len(Pop))
   ```
2. You never need to instantiate `Model` directly; Just `MCMC`:

   ```
   mc=pymc.MCMC([serobservation,pobservation,prob])
   ```

With these changes, I get 8 GOF plots, one for each datum. [Here is a zip file](http://d.pr/f/1cDjj) containing the plots that I got.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by this. How exactly do you call `expval`? Do you pass it the trace of `pobservation`?

Comment: Every distribution (stochastic node) in PyMC has a `expval` method. We probably should have just had the function extract it automatically. Keep in mind you don't need this for  `got_plot`, only for `discrepancy_plot`.